# ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1452

I have created two tables in MySQL 5.6.11 as shown below by means of MySQL Workbench 5.2.47.

The `country` table:

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `country` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INC

REMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

The `state_table`:

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `state_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `state_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `country_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `country` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT=''$$
```

There is one row in the `country` table with the `id` 1. It allows only one (child) row to be inserted into its child table `state_table`. If more rows are attempted, then the following error occurs.

> ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint
>   fails (`social_networking`.`state_table`, CONSTRAINT `country_fk`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `country` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON
>   UPDATE CASCADE)

SQL Statement:

```
INSERT INTO `social_networking`.`state_table` (`id`, `state_name`, `country_id`) VALUES ('2', 'xxx', '1')
```

Actually, I'm trying to map these tables using an ORM (JPA) where I always see only `OneToOne` relationship.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you have a typo in your foreign key constraint, `country_id` should probaby be the foreign key to `country`. When `id` is the foreign key, you can only insert one row since it just happens to get id=1 which is the same id as the row in country;

```
CONSTRAINT `country_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) 
    REFERENCES `country` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

should probably be

```
CONSTRAINT `country_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) 
    REFERENCES `country` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6782/2).

Comment: Thank you but the name of the primary key of all the tables is `id`.

Comment: @Tiny Yes, but you want `state_table.country_id` to reference the `country.id` column. What you have now is that the `state_table.id` column references `country.id`, which only allows exactly one state per country and vice versa.

Comment: I have renamed the column name  `id` of each table and made it  meaningful like `country_id`, `state_id`, `city_id`... I didn't notice these DDL statements because the tables have been created by MySQL Workbench. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

Well, I find the answer, the solution, my english is not very well but I think can explain you. I get this error after try to create a trigger, My database was created in phpmyadmin, and this error was make me crazy, the problem was that I before create the trigger, I load a lot of data in my tables, and in my child table was some data that have no match in my parent table, ej: my child table "chat" have a "id_jugador=1" and in my parent table there wasn't that "id_jugador", that was my mistake, I hope help you, Argentina Rulz ;)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and it was not wrong relationships name.
I had problem with different records, ie, tried registering a record that did not exist in another table so generated this error.
Check if the record exists in another table to insert their correct relationship, otherwise, this error appears.

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
example:
 table1(
    id1 INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name1 VARCHAR(50)
 )
 table2(
    id2,<--- want to add FOREIGN KEY to this field
    name2 VARCHAR(50)
 )
```

Before adding constraint foreign key you must have the right value between `id1` and `id2`, so you should update that id field with the value that map each other.

Answer (score -1):

#### Possible Solution

if you have live data, then check all column values.

i.e. if you have 'x'->table as primary one having 'a'->column and 'y'->table as secondary with 'b'->column, then all values in 'b'->column must exist in 'a'->column if any value that exists in 'b'->column and not exist in 'a'->column then it will give as such error..

Hope this help.. for newbie..