# Error 145: Cannot add or update a child row within inserting data into database .. mySQL

Tags: mysql, database, bash, foreign-key-relationship

I have created a database in MySQL and script to add data into that database. But when I want to add some data to my Pnumbers table, I have this problem.

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`blahari1/Pnumbers`, CONSTRAINT `Pnumbers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customerID`) REFERENCES `Customers` (`ID`))
```

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Implementation of database:

```
USE blahari1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Calls;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Pnumbers;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Customers;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Operators;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Tarifs;

CREATE TABLE Customers (
  ID INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_czech_ci;

CREATE TABLE Operators (
ID INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_czech_ci;

CREATE TABLE Tarifs (
  ID INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  Name VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_czech_ci;

CREATE TABLE Pnumbers (
  ID INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  pnumber VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  minutes INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  customerID INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  operatorID INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  tarifID INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (customerID) REFERENCES Customers (ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (operatorID) REFERENCES Operators (ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (tarifID) REFERENCES Tarifs (ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_czech_ci;

CREATE TABLE Calls (
  ID INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  length INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  fk_PNFrom INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  fk_PNTo INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (fk_PNFrom) REFERENCES Pnumbers (ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (fk_PNTo) REFERENCES Pnumbers (ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_czech_ci;
```

The script that should add data to the database:

```
#!/bin/bash
# blahari1
LOGIN="mysql --user=blahari1 --password=animate --database=blahari1"

#-------------
insertion() {
    if [ "$1" == "numbers" ]; then
        while read line; do
            name="`echo $line | sed 's/,.*//'`";
            numberV="`echo $line | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/,.*//'`";
            operatorV="`echo $line | awk '{print $3}' | sed 's/,.*//'`";
            tarifV="`echo $line | awk '{print $4}' | sed 's/,.*//'`";
            minutesV="`echo $line | awk '{print $5}'`";
            if [ ! "`echo "SELECT name '' FROM Customers WHERE name='$name';" | $LOGIN`" ]; then
                echo "INSERT INTO Customers (name) VALUES ('$name');" | $LOGIN
            fi
            if [ ! "`echo "SELECT name '' FROM Operators WHERE name='$operatorV';" | $LOGIN`" ]; then
                echo "INSERT INTO Operators (name) VALUES ('$operatorV');" | $LOGIN
            fi
            if [ ! "`echo "SELECT name '' FROM Tarifs WHERE name='$tarifV';" | $LOGIN`" ]; then
                echo "INSERT INTO Tarifs (name) VALUES ('$tarifV');" | $LOGIN
            fi
            idC="`echo "SELECT ID FROM Customers WHERE name='$name';" | $LOGIN`";
            idO="`echo "SELECT ID FROM Operators WHERE name='$operatorV';" | $LOGIN`";
            idT="`echo "SELECT ID FROM Tarifs WHERE name='$tarifV';" | $LOGIN`";
            echo "INSERT INTO Pnumbers (pnumber, operatorID, tarifID, minutes, customerID) VALUES ('$numberV', '$idO', '$idT', '$minutesV', '$idC');" | $LOGIN;
        done < customers.txt
    elif [ "$1" == "calls" ]; then
        while read line; do
            fromV="`echo $line | sed 's/,.*//'`";
            fromV="`echo "SELECT ID FROM Pnumbers WHERE pnumber='$fromV';" | $LOGIN`";
            toV="`echo $line | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/,.*//'`";
            toV="`echo "SELECT ID FROM Pnumbers WHERE pnumber='$toV';" | $LOGIN`";
            lengthV="`echo $line | awk '{print $3}'`";
            echo "INSERT INTO Calls (fk_PNFrom, fk_PNTo, length) VALUES ('$fromV', '$toV', '$lengthV');" | $LOGIN;
        done < calls.txt
    fi
    echo "SELECT * FROM Customers;" | $LOGIN
    echo "SELECT * FROM Operators;" | $LOGIN
    echo "SELECT * FROM Pnumbers;" | $LOGIN
    echo "SELECT * FROM Tarifs;" | $LOGIN
    echo "SELECT * FROM Calls;" | $LOGIN
}

queries(){

if [ "$1" = "calls" ];then
    id="`echo "SELECT NumbersFrom.number as PNFrom, NumbersTo.number as PNTo 
        FROM Calls, Pnumbers as NumbersFrom,Pnumbers as NumbersTo, Operators
        WHERE Operators.name = '$1' AND Operators.ID = NumbersFrom.operatorID AND  Calls.fk_PNFrom = NumbersFrom.ID
        AND Calls.fk_PNTo = NumbersTo.ID;" | $LOGIN`"
    echo "$id"
    elif [ "$1" = "credit" ];then
      kredit="`echo "SELECT (SELECT SUM(Pnumbers.minutes) FROM Pnumbers, Customers
            WHERE Customers.name = '$1' AND Customers.ID = Pnumbers.customerID) - SUM(Calls.length)
            FROM Customers,Pnumbers,Calls
            WHERE Customers.name = '$1' AND Customers.ID = Pnumbers.customerID AND Pnumbers.ID = Calls.fk_PNFrom;" | $LOGIN`"  
    echo "$kredit"
    elif [ "$1" = "maxcalls" ];then
    maxcalls="`echo "SELECT Customers.name FROM Customers, Pnumbers, Calls 
    WHERE Customers.ID = Pnumbers.customerID AND Pnumbers.ID = Calls.fk_PNFrom
    GROUP BY Customers.ID ORDER BY SUM(Calls.length) DESC LIMIT 1;" | $LOGIN`"      
    echo "$maxcalls"

    elif [ "$1" = "longest" ];then
    maxlength="`echo "SELECT Customers.name FROM Customers,Pnumbers AS NumbersFrom,Pnumbers AS NumbersTo, Calls, Operators 
    WHERE Operators.name = '$1' AND Operators.ID = NumbersFrom.operatorID AND Customers.ID = NumbersTo.customerID
    AND NumbersTo.ID = Calls.fk_PNTo AND NumbersFrom.ID = Calls.fk_PNFrom 
    ORDER BY Calls.length DESC LIMIT 1;" | $LOGIN`"
    echo "$maxlength"

        #response=`echo "select person.name from phone_number, calls, person where person.id = phone_number.personId and phone_number.id=calls.receipienId and select calls.receipienId where calls.length=max(calls.length);" | $LOGIN`
fi
}


if [ "$1" = "--variant" ]; then
    echo "5"
elif [ "$1" = "--insert" ];then 
    insertion "$2" "$3"
elif [ "$1" = "--query" ];then
    queries "$2" "$3"
elif [ "$1" = "--debug" ];then
    echo "debug"
fi
```

Thank you so much for any help. thank you

Comment: @user1613360 He just inserted them, and then he's SELECTing the IDs on the lines right before the `INSERT`. Don't they have to exist?

Comment: Check this out.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16447137/error-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `--skip-column-names` option on the `mysql` command. Otherwise, the output from your `SELECT` statement will be something like:

```
ID
123
```

and you'll try to insert this two-line string into the `Pnumbers` table. When it tries to convert it to an integer, it will convert to `0`, which doesn't exist in the `Customer` table.
So use:

```
LOGIN="mysql --user=blahari1 --password=animate --database=blahari1 --skip-column-names"
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have NULL values in your one of your foreign key, try to get rid of those first.

Comment: How would he get null values? They're primary keys of the other tables, and they use `AUTO_INCREMENT`, so they can't be null.